# TypeError: oes.addValidationError is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, jestjs

### Update

[Jest Issue Report](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/7223)

I narrowed this down somewhat.  The value of `oes` is somehow being switched from an Object to the boolean value `true` right in the middle of the function and the switch gets logged twice.  It's really bizarre.  This is what I inserted into the `validateProperty` function on line 64:

```
const propertyValue = o[propertyName];

console.log("OES LINE 64: ", oes);

console.log src/utilities/utilities.ts:64
OES LINE 64:  ObjectErrors { valid: true, errors: [], cache: {} }

console.log src/utilities/utilities.ts:64
OES LINE 64:  true
```

It looks as if somehow the runtime is able to switch the value of the `oes` while the function call is running ... I'm guessing it's some sort of Jest bug, but it really should not be happening at all since only one test is running.

[I committed the whole repository with my logging statements in tact in case anyone wants to look at what I have described above](https://github.com/fireflysemantics/validator).

### Original Question

Running this test with Jest and for the for the below code the runtime is logging `TypeError: oes.addValidationError is not a function`.

```
  90 |         );
  91 |         console.log("THIS IS THE FUNCTION: ", oes.addValidationError);
> 92 |         oes.addValidationError(ve);
     |             ^
  93 |         oes.valid = false;
  94 |       }
  95 |     }
```

As can be seen I'm logging what `oes.addValidationError` is.  The log output looks like this:

```
console.log src/utilities/utilities.ts:91
THIS IS THE FUNCTION:  undefined

console.log src/utilities/utilities.ts:91
THIS IS THE FUNCTION:  function (ve) {
        var key = utilities_1.getObjectPropertyKey(ve.vc.target.name, ve.vc.propertyName);
        this.errors.push(ve);
        this.pushtIfAbsent(key, ve);
    }
```

So it looks like the function is undefined the first time the log statement is attempted and then all of a sudden it defines itself.

[This is the class that the `oes` instance is constructor from.](https://github.com/fireflysemantics/validator/blob/master/src/container/error/ObjectErrors.ts).  As can be seen the instance does have the method defined.

[And this is the test that caused the strange behavior](https://github.com/fireflysemantics/validator/blob/master/src/decorators/IfValid.spec.ts)

To see this in action:

```
  git clone https://github.com/fireflysemantics/validator
```

And then run:

```
`npm t src/decorators/IfValid.spec.ts`
```

If I comment out most of the test and just run this:

```
let oes = new ObjectErrors();
expect(typeof oes.addValidationError === "function").toBeTruthy();
```

The test passes ...

Comment: check for  you declare your script before usage

Comment: This is the test that triggers it: https://github.com/fireflysemantics/validator/blob/master/src/decorators/IfValid.spec.ts

Comment: Also See the additional test I performed and just added to the bottom of the question.

Answer (score 0):

It's been fixed.  For me the tests were running even though there were compile errors, so I think it's an issue with `ts-jest`.  [Opened another issue there](https://github.com/kulshekhar/ts-jest/issues/821).